# Updating the value of another property when a DependencyProperty changes

Tags: wpf, properties

I have a DependencyProperty in my UserControl with a property changed callback. The property works as expected and the callback works as expected.

```
public double CurrentFlow
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentFlowProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentFlowProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentFlowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentFlow", typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnCurrentFlowPropertyChanged));

private static void OnCurrentFlowPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentFlow changed.");
}
```

However, I have a TextBlock in my UserControl where I want to display CurrentFlow as a formatted string. Currently, I have the Text property of the TextBlock binded to CurrentFlow, and it works, but I'm not getting the format I need. (Too many numbers after the decimal.)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentFlow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a property named CurrentFlowString that takes the value from CurrentFlow and formats it to what I want. For example: CurrentFlow.ToString("0.00");

What's the best way to go about this with DependencyProperties? I know how to do this with regular properties but I'm kinda stuck here.

Thanks!

Comment: `StringFormat={0:F2}` on the Binding should work.

Comment: StringFormat=0.00 and StringFormat=0 work and seem to do what I want. Are the curly braces only necessary for certain types of formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have more flexibility than using `StringFormat`, you can also use a custom converter. For example,

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double d)
            return $"{d:f2}";
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then add it to your `UserControl.Resources`, and use it in your `Binding`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentFlow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

**Solution 2**:
Based on your comment below, here's an alternative solution. First, create a new dependency property; for example, `FormattedCurrentFlow`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedCurrentFlowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FormattedCurrentFlow", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string FormattedCurrentFlow
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FormattedCurrentFlowProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FormattedCurrentFlowProperty, value); }
}
```

Since you already have a method to handle changes in `CurrentFlow`, update the new `FormattedCurrentFlow` when `CurrentFlow` changes:

```
private static void OnCurrentFlowPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myControl = (MyControl)source;
    myControl.FormattedCurrentFlow = $"{myControl.CurrentFlow:f2}";
}
```

The `TextBox` in the `UserControl` can now bind to `FormattedCurrentFlow`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedCurrentFlow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Luckily, I don't need anything too complex. StringFormat=0 does the trick.

However, I guess my question is more about how to update other properties than just StringFormatting.

For example, let's say I set the property ControlColor to a particular color. I have a few other properties that I want to use that color in their own values. Like a SolidColorBrush using ControlColor as the color it uses. If that makes sense.

Comment: @n0kx I think I understand what you mean. I've added a second solution to my answer that hopefully addresses this.